# mysql, dump, database restore

Tags: mysql, database, dump

I have dumped my database with the following command:

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword db_name > file
```

then I completely removed my database:

```
drop database db_name;
```

then I created a new database:

```
create database db_name;
```

and then I tried to restore the db with the following command:

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword db_name < file
```

The problem is that dump does not create tables and loads data in them and so the database remains empty however it does show a message like dump completed "date time"

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: You simply need to use `mysql -uXXX -pXXX < dump_file.sql`. (i.e.: `mysqldump` is only for exporting data, not importing it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

mysqldump is for dumping the database. You've created a new empty database, and then dumped that empty database. Use `mysql` instead to reload your dump

```
mysqldump db > dump.sql
mysql drop/create
mysql db < dump.sql
```

would be the basic command sequence.

Answer (score 14):

I like to do the following to restore.

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword
create database db;
use db;
source dump.sql;
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried dump of  my database with the following commands:

```
#mysqldump -u <username> -p <password> DB_name > <filename>.sql
```

Then login into the DB:

```
   #mysql -u <username> -p <password>
   >show databases;
   >drop database <DB_name>;
```

Then create a new database:

```
#create database <DB_name>;
```

DB_name is userdefined name we can have any name.

and then restore the DB with the following command:

```
#mysql -u <username> -p <password> DB_name < <filename>.sql
```